# are docker intermediate layers stored anywhere except the cache OR can they be backed up

Tags: docker

I recently had to delete my docker vm as it was huge and would not respond to the usual downsizing commands.

When I went to rebuild my images it started from layer 0. This is a problem as it updates all the packages and you end up with a completely different image to the original.

Where is the cache stored? Is it available in the dockerhub? Can it be backed up?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a Docker VM like `docker-machine` obviously the layers are stored on it (e.g. something like `/var/lib/docker/image/overlay2`), so you will lose any caching due to the previous buildings.

Keep in mind that if you want to optimize your images you have to perform vendor installation nearly the end of the statements in order to maximize the use of upper layers cache.

Comment: I thought docker was great because it fixes the environment. However now I have a working image but no idea of what versions of packages it has in it; and I can't make any changes to my source code in the last layer without updating all the others.

Comment: Docker is not a silver bullet: you have to perform version-pinning of system dependencies and be aware of building the base image.